# change the width table view cell and used one image for two cell

Tags: ios, uikit

How can I use single image for two cell as shown in the image

[image]

Comment: uk2302  Thank you corrected image!

Comment: What do you exactly mean? one image for used: - free: - testlabel or hide image for 'settings' ?

Comment: "free" and "testLabel" lines show date of core data. Setting transition other controller.

Comment: maybe the best way to create one single cell, which will contain all your labels and one single image. Is this suggestion you want ?

Comment: I tried it, but it does not fit. in some cell "free" and "used" will be transition to another controller. all parts application consists of such parts.

Comment: You can place transparent uibutton in front of your labels as compromise or replace labels on uibutoon (better way). Add your navigation logic as buttons' selectors

Comment: Could you please explain how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place uibutton instead of your labels as compromise. (on the image below you can see how to do that)

[image]
 Add your navigation logic as buttons' selectors in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:<#@"reuseIdentifier"#> forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

// add action manually for your button
    cell.FirstSegueButton addTarget:self action:@selector(FirstSegueButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```